# Javascript dosn't work in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have keep fighting with interesting error. My Javascript code won't work in bootstrap modal.

I am using `"Dropzone.js"` file uploading system.
Problem is there: It loads dropzone.js, but won't load my custom js, that changes dropzone.js Input field are located at one of many modals.

I tried if I put input field any other place not in modal, it loads my custom script, but when its in modal, it dosn't load.

Adding scripts:

```
<link href="../Style/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../Style/vendors/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../Style/vendors/pnotify/dist/pnotify.nonblock.js"></script>
<script src="../Style/vendors/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#image_upload_panel').on('shown', function() {
    Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 10,
    maxFiles: 1,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
    acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
    init:function(){
      var self = this;
      // config
      self.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
      self.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
      //New file added
      self.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        console.log('new file added ', file);
      });
      // Send file starts
      self.on("sending", function (file) {
        console.log('upload started', file);
        $('.meter').show();
      });

      // File upload Progress
      self.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
        console.log("progress ", progress);
        $('.roller').width(progress + '%');
      });

      self.on("queuecomplete", function (progress) {
        $('.meter').delay(999).slideUp(999);
      });

      // On removing file
      self.on("removedfile", function (file) {
        console.log(file);
      });
    }
    };
  });
</script>
```

Button that opens modal :

```
<a id="post_upload" class="post_upload" style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".image_upload"><button type="submit" name="btn-upload" id="btn-upload" class="btn btn-danger ">Upload Image</button></a>
```

And modal:

```
<!-- Image Upload -->
<div class="modal fade image_upload" id="image_upload_panel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="dropzone" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="uploadWidget">
                <b><center><div class="modal-header">Upload Post</div></center></b>
                <center><input type="text" name="title" style="margin-top:20px; width:60%; height:35px; text-align:center;" placeholder="Here goes title!" /></center>
                <hr>
                <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>Drop or select your file!</span></div>
                <div class="modal-footer"><button type="submit" id="uploadPostForm" name="uploadPostForm" class="btn btn-primary ">Upload</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF Image Upload -->
```

Comment: Is #image_upload_panel modal dynamically generated, or is it hidden in the page?

Comment: @BrianGottier It is hidden in page. And shown when button clicked.

Comment: According to the docs, it looks like your form id should be upload-widget, not uploadWidget. It says that in the configuration section of this page: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation

Comment: @BrianGottier I have implemented this code in different pages too. They all works, like this, only not in modal.

Comment: How about a line change like this: `$(document).on('shown', '#image_upload_panel', function() {`

Comment: Still nothing changes.

Comment: Is this bootstrap 4? I got it working, but I'm using bootstrap 4 beta.

Comment: @BrianGottier It's bootstrap 3

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it matters. I think your event needs to be "shown.bs.modal" not just "shown". At least that's what I'm seeing when I look at docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't wait for your response to my question asking if this is **bootstrap 4**. I've got to leave in a few minutes, and I'm hoping this solves your problem. If not, let me know and I'll see what I can do. See the comments in the code, but I got this working, and the local config was being applied:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // The bootstrap 4 modal event is "shown.bs.modal", not just "shown"
    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#image_upload_panel', function() {

        // I am using the jQuery method of creating the dropzone.
        // Using #uploadWidget here would not work for me. 
        $("#image_upload_panel").dropzone({
            url: '/kookoopapa'
        });
    });

    // I'm automating the opening of the modal on page load,
    // then selecting a file. A 404 page not found error verifies
    // that the local config is being applied to the dropzone.
    $('#image_upload_panel').modal();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but nothing changes. :(

Comment: Oh, It took 3 days and I found out my problem, and trying to solve it now. Its not in modal.. Its in page. (Got fun.php where select images from db (hundreds) and script wont load. If it dont select images, my dropzone works)